# Will rain affect the growth of crops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Will rain speed up the growth of seedlings, sugarcane, wheat, melons and pumpkin seeds?[image]

Comment: Wow, until I blew that picture up and stared for a while, my eyes were screaming "optical illusion!" at that. The right and left sections of cobblestone blend together.

Comment: really i can easily tell the difference

Comment: rain only effects the rate of fishing!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code that determines the rate of growth is:

```
getGrowthRate(crop)
{
    if (crop.getBlockBelow().isHydrated())
        growthRate = 4.0;
    else
        growthRate = 2.0;

    for (farmland in crop.getFarmlandIn8BlocksBelow()) //Immediately surrounding Farmland with crops
    {
        if (farmland.isHydrated())
            growthRate = growthRate + 0.75
        else
            growthRate = growthRate + 0.25
    }

    if (crop.hasNeighborCropOnNS() and crop.hasNeighborCropOnEW()) //If (north OR south) AND (east OR west) have crops
        growthRate = growthRate / 2;
    else if (crop.hasNeighborCropDiagonally()) //If any immediately diagonal square has a crop
        growthRate = growthRate / 2;

    return growthRate;
}
```

`isHydrated()` returns whether a farmland block is moistened or not. Rain does not make farmland moist any quicker than normal.

So the answer is **no**, rain does not affect the rate of growth of crops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a very simple answer, no, unless you have a mod or a server plugin to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Rain hydrates farmland if it isn't already. In the absence of water, if the farmland is not hydrated then rain will in fact speed up the growing process for the duration.